# How to integrate MS Bot with Webex teams using botbulilder webex adapter using node js

Tags: node.js, botframework, webex

I am trying to integrate MS Bot developed in node js with webex teams using botbuilder webex adapter as follows

```
//creating webex adapter for bot channel
const adapter = new WebexAdapter({
access_token: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,
public_address: process.env.PUBLIC_ADDRESS,
secret: process.env.SECRET });
```

when try to run I am getting this warning
[message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcwA3.png)
Need some solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the signature in the headings is not matching your secret hash. Here is the relevant part of the code which is throwing this error.

```
if (this.options.secret) {
   const signature = req.headers['x-spark-signature'];
   const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha1', this.options.secret).update(JSON.stringify(payload)).digest('hex');
   if (signature !== hash) {
      console.warn('WARNING: Webhook received message with invalid signature. Potential malicious behavior!');
      return false;
   }
}
```

You need to check that you have the correct signature in the request header and that you have set the correct secret in you bot options.

Reference on Github: https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/blob/master/packages/botbuilder-adapter-webex/src/webex_adapter.ts